# Typo to Joomla Migrations?

Tags: mysql, joomla, typo3

Can anyone give me some insight into CMS migrations from Typo to Joomla? I have a fairly large Typo site that needs to be updated and put into Joomla on a new host. I'm most concerned about the database side. Both sites use MySQL but at some point I'm going to have to do a data migration between the two and I have no idea if there are major pitfalls along the way. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Are you talking about **[Typo](https://github.com/fdv/typo/)** or **[TYPO3](http://typo3.org/)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked around on Google, I couldn't find anything about migrating from Typo to Joomla. I assume the migration would be far too complex as they are completely different system and Typo isn't as popular as the likes of wordpress. To be honest, you might want to consider starting the Joomla site from scratch.

[Download Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/download)

I'm not sure what extensions you are currently using on your site, but I'm sure the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) will provide you with most things that suit your needs.

As for template, I'm not sure if you want to use commercial or non-commercial ones, so I'll provide a bit of both.

**Commercial:**

[Yootheme](http://yootheme.com) and [Rockettheme](http://rockettheme.com) have always been my first choices when it comes to templates, due to reliability, style and mobile compatibility.

**Non-commercial:**

Yootheme's [Master Theme](http://www.yootheme.com/themes/warp-framework) is completely free which is based on their Warp framework. It's a fairly basic template but with some modifications, it can be made to look better. [Shape5](http://www.shape5.com/product_details/free_templates/) provide 3 free templates, Vertex being my favourite. [Joomlart](http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/showcase?tag=free&catid=28) have 2 free templates. Finally, [JoomForest](http://www.joomforest.com/joomforest-templates/joomla-templates/free-joomla-templates.html) provide 2 free templates, JF-Corporate being my favourite as it also comes with a template for the Kunena Forum and JomSocial, which good and free ones are hard to come across.

I know this didn't answer your questions but I would definitely recommend starting from scratch as it will most likely save you the hassle.

Comment: It goes beyond simple templates. They have 10,000 users in Typo so, as stated in my question, the main concern is doing the database migration from Typo to Joomla. Starting from scratch in Joomla is simply not an option.